# How to write the Perl script for comparing the multi-line text of a both scalars?

Tags: regex, perl

I have two strings.

String 1:

```
logging on
enable secret 5 $1$okZh$nSIVWr7vNHAqk231PisjN0
snmp-server community sph1nkx5 v1default RO 5
snmp-server ifindex persist
tacacs-server timeout 5
tacacs-server key 7 xxx
```

String 2:

```
logging on


enable secret 5 xxx
snmp-server community  xxx
snmp-server ifindex persist
tacacs-server timeout 5
tacacs-server key 7 00070A160C5E190A002247
```

I want to compare both string by ignoring white spaces & some line which staring with "enable secret" ,"snmp-server community" & "tacacs-server key".

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't offer advice on your code if you don't include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the stuff you want to ignore before doing the comparison.

```
for ($str1, $str2) {
   s/^(?:enable secret|snmp-server community|tacacs-server key)[^\n]*\n//mg;
   s/\s+//g;
}

$str1 eq $str2
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami,But i there is some error. i am using below code.
[code]#!/usr/bin/perl
$str1='logging on
enable secret 5 $1$okZh$nSIVWr7vNHAqk231PisjN0
snmp-server community sph1nkx5 v1default RO 5
snmp-server ifindex persist
tacacs-server timeout 5
tacacs-server key 7 xxx'
$str2='logging on


enable secret 5 xxx
snmp-server community  xxx
snmp-server ifindex persist
tacacs-server timeout 5
tacacs-server key 7 00070A160C5E190A002247'

for ($str1, $str2) {
   s/^(?:enable secret|snmp-server community|tacacs-server key)[^\n]*\n//mg;
   s/\s+//g;
}
$str1 eq $str2[code]

Comment: Lack of semicolons?

Comment: Also, always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` (which means you'll also have to declare your vars, as you should.)